# Why don't I get "NEW.value" values ​in the BEFORE UPDATE trigger?

Tags: sql, mysql, triggers, mariadb

I wrote a simple trigger that, before UPDATE a table, enters data into other tables. Everything would be fine, but the values ​​of NEW.id or NEW.object_id are empty if they are used without DECLARE a new variable and without entering data into this variable via SET. But even here I failed, because after entering data into the variable I receive data like NAME_CONST ('new_id_object',5159).

If you register a debug in the trigger, then in debug message everything writes beautifully as it should be

```
<------><------>    22 Query<-->SIGNAL SQLSTATE '45000' SET MESSAGE_TEXT =  NAME_CONST('debug_message',_utf8mb3'Debug: NEW.object_id=14, NEW.id=5024, NEW.date1=2021-02-08, NEW.type=1, NEW.cid=6968' COLLATE 'utf8mb3<------><------>    22 Query<-->commit
```

Here is my TRIGGER №1:

```
BEGIN
  DECLARE new_object_id INT;
  SET new_object_id = NEW.object_id;
  GET DIAGNOSTICS new_object_id = NUMBER;
  -- Now you can use new_object_id directly in your trigger logic
  -- For example, you can use it in the INSERT statement
  IF new_object_id != 999 THEN
    INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, `value`) VALUES (new_object_id, 1, '123');
  END IF;
END
```

phone_client_item_1 table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `phone_client_item_1` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `cid` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `type` tinyint(4) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `source_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `date1` date DEFAULT NULL,
  `date2` date DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `date1` (`date1`),
  KEY `date2` (`date2`),
  KEY `cid` (`cid`),
  KEY `object_id` (`object_id`),
  KEY `source_id` (`source_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB AUTO_INCREMENT=5689 DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

object_param_value_text table structure

```
CREATE TABLE `object_param_value_text` (
  `object_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `param_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT 0,
  `value` varchar(250) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`param_id`,`object_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_unicode_ci;
```

The SQL queries themselves for UPDATE and the query generated by the trigger

```
<------><------>    42 Prepare<>UPDATE phone_client_item_1 SET cid=?, type=?, source_id=?, date1=?, date2=?,  comment=?, object_id=?, alias=? WHERE id=?
<------><------>    42 Execute<>UPDATE phone_client_item_1 SET cid=6968, type=1, source_id=7, date1=DATE'2021-01-13', date2=NULL,  comment='[LOCAL] ???? ?????', object_id=14, alias='' WHERE id=4990
<------><------>    42 Query<-->INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, `value`) VALUES ( NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14), 1, '123')
```

Before this, I wrote a trigger for another table and everything worked there perfectly as intended. Here is my old trigger just for example to show how i expected it to work.

TRIGGER №2

```
BEGIN

    -- Get the last inserted ID from the object table
    SELECT `AUTO_INCREMENT` INTO @object_id
    FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES
    WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = 'bgbilling'
    AND TABLE_NAME = 'object';

    -- Modify the values before insert
    SET NEW.date1 = NOW();
    
    -- Use LPAD within CONCAT to format object_id with leading zeros directly
    IF NEW.type_id = 1 THEN
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 3, CONCAT('sp_', NEW.cid, '-', LPAD(@object_id, 5, '0')));
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 2, CAST(SUBSTRING(MD5(RAND()), 1, 12) AS CHAR));
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_list (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 10, 16);
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_list (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 11, 20);
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_list (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 12, 21);
        INSERT INTO object_param_value_flag (object_id, param_id, `value`) 
            VALUES (@object_id, 13, 0);
    END IF;
END
```

How can I roughly make my new TRIGGER №1 to work as expected? I need to get data from NEW.column_name which should be interger and use it in SQL query generated by trigger. To get final query like `INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, value) VALUES (new_object_id, 1, '123');`

Now for example if im trying to get values from NEW.column_name or OLD.column_name SQL query generated by my trigger will look like

`INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id,` value`) VALUES (NEW.object_id, 1, '123')`

As you can see, NEW.object_id stayed as a text. Value wasnt get from it.

And if im trying to get values through declaring variables and using them instead of NEW.column_name LIKE

```
DECLARE new_object_id INT;
SET new_object_id = NEW.object_id;
```

Im having as a result of trigger work - SQL query like
`INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id,` value`) VALUES ( NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14), 1, '123')`
Where NAME_CONST is not what i expected to see.

### **UPD1**

Also i tried `BEFORE UPDATE` and `AFTER UPDATE` both in 2 ways to get this values from "new" variables. `NEW.object_id` i tried to SET in new declared variable and then use it. `NEW.date1` i tried to use without any manipulation.

Here is result from queries log file

As you can see declared variable value is `NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14)`. And `NEW.date1` variable not treated as a variable.

```
<------><------>    42 Close stmt
<------><------>    42 Prepare<>UPDATE phone_client_item_1 SET cid=?, type=?, source_id=?, date1=?, date2=?,  comment=?, object_id=?, alias=? WHERE id=?
<------><------>    42 Execute<>UPDATE phone_client_item_1 SET cid=6968, type=1, source_id=7, date1=DATE'2021-01-13', date2=NULL,  comment='[LOCAL] ???? ?????', object_id=14, alias='' WHERE id=499
<------><------>    42 Query<-->INSERT INTO object_param_value_text (object_id, param_id, `value`) VALUES ( NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14), 1, NEW.date1)
```

Comment: What kind of a new value do you expect to get in a before trigger?

Comment: @Shadow 

some kind of software generating SQL query to update an object in database

SQL query look like this:
Execute<>UPDATE phone_client_item_1 SET cid=6968, type=1, source_id=7, date1=DATE'2021-01-13', date2=NULL,  comment='[LOCAL] ???? ?????', object_id=14, alias='' WHERE id=4990

So, im trying to create a trigger which will get values of object_id, id, date1 or other columns into new.object_id, new.id, new.date1. And then im trying to use this values in my INSERT INTO

Finaly i expected new.object_id to be 14 (integer) as it is in SQL UPDATE generated by software.

Comment: Try in after update trigger

Comment: @Shadow i tried it before. No luck.
 I tried before and after both in 2 ways. With DECLARE and then SET variable = NEW.variable.
And just calling NEW.variable.
The result is different but not as expected.

Comment: I'll be honeat, I cannot follow the question! Are you setting a session variable @object_new_id in a trigger and expect it to be in NEW.object_id in another? The sequemce of events, statements triggering them and what you are trying to achieve are all unclear to me.

Comment: In a before update trigger all existing table values are written to the NEW and OLD tables, the columns to be updated in the set clauses of the update statement then overwrite the relevant columns in the NEW table. There is no need to set a local variable to acquire the NEW values , if they are null or empty then that's what they were in the table or what the UPDATE statement set them to.  see https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/miscellaneous-functions.html#function_name-const for discussion of name_const function

Comment: @P.Salmon if you can check the last row before UPD1 in my post you will see that there is no values for/from NEW and OLD tables if i try to use them directly without declaring other variables for them. In that case i tried to check what values am i getting with declared variables and values from NEW table.
If variable was declared and set equal to value from NEW table there will be result like NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14). If not and NEW.column was used to get new value there will be nothing, "NEW.column_name" wouldnt be treated as a variable.
Also please check last row from UPD1.

Comment: @Shadow sorry for that. Looks like language barier. I'll try to clarify.
Please check second code block. There is my trigger which is problematic. I really cant understand why i cant just use NEW.column_name before update to get values from UPDATE query. In last code block in UPD1 you can see INSERT INTO query which was generated by my trigger with 3 values. NAME_CONST('new_object_id',14), 1 and NEW.date1. So the main question is why does "NEW.date1" remain just "NEW.date1" in the finished query and values wasnt get from it? And why if i do SET NEW.date1 to new variable - i can get a value.

Comment: Ok please fix your table structures , publish the results of show create table for both tables and I'll have another look

Comment: @P.Salmon I just changed the data structure of the tables, bringing them into a normal readable form. I apologize for not doing this initially, I am still poorly familiar with SQL and the form in which information must be provided.

Answer (score 0):

No.

Use `LAST_INSERT_ID()`.  It is simpler and safer than rummaging around in `information_schema`.

Comment: Last_insert_id is not set during an update, is it?